# PostgreSQL jsonb?

Tags: postgresql

Which is better, to store config data into single jsonb field or dedicate a field for each property key?

For example, this json data:

```
{
  notifications: {
    check: {
      enabled: true,
      In_delimiters: true,
      Out_delimiters : false
    },
    battery_low: {
      enabled: true,
      battery_power: 0.70
    },
    gps_on: {
      enabled: true
    },
    gps_off: {
      enabled: true
    },
    speed_exceeded: {
      enabled: true,
      speed: 100
    }
  }
}
```

If I have thousands of users, each property key will be duplicated in each row, making the DB size grow bigger than if I dedicate a field for each property and store value only.

What's the advice in this case? Shall I go with jsonb and use compression? or dedicate a filed for each property?

Comment: json is good for unstructured data. Otherwise do not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of database size first; storage is comparatively cheap these days.

Use `json` or `jsonb` if

1. the structure varies from entry to entry, making it hard to come up with a relational data model
2. there is not much processing of the values inside the database

Otherwise use a relational data model, that's what a relational database is best at.

If you don't process the data inside the database at all and saving storage is important to you, use `json` – if your row size exceeds 2KB, it will be compressed automatically.
`json` is also the way to go if you have an object key order, white space or duplicate object keys that need to be preserved.

If you have to use the data in queries, use `jsonb` by all means.
The operators are faster, and you can use indexes.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you write _processing of the values inside the database_?

Comment: Use JSON functions in SQL queries. Use indexes on JSON columns. Basically, do anything more than just storing and retrieving the JSON values.